# Merging two maps c++

Tags: c++, maps

I have created two maps of the form:

[event number][mass]      called map results_JMass

and

[event number][ momentum]   called map results_PhotonPt

Both maps have the same key (event number) which is an integer and contains Doubles as the values. I'd like to create a third map of the form:

[event number][mass][momentum]

I know I need to use

```
  std::map <Int_t, std::vector< pair <Double_t,Double_t> > > new_map;
```

But I'm not sure how to combine the two maps to create the third.

This is what I have come up with:

```
   for (auto& kv3 : results_JMass) { //Iterates the data with kv3 as the iterator and the results_jMass what kv3 is iterating through
   event_number = kv3.first; //Iterator for the first index, i.e the events
   m = kv3.second;  //iterator for the second index i.e the masses

   new_map [event_number].first = m;

   for (auto&kv4: results_PhotonPt) {
 event_number = kv4.first;
 p = kv4.second;

 new_map [event_number].second = p;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are the two maps guaranteed to contain the same set of event numbers?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but what is `Int_t` and `Double_t`? Are they normal `int` and `double`? Why the custom type-names?

Comment: It seems to me that the correct way to express the map should be: `std::map <Int_t, std::pair <Double_t,Double_t>> new_map;`

Comment: For my area of work (particle physics) they use Int_t and Double_t but they mean the same as int and double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 100% sure, that both maps have exactly the same keys, then one loop is enough:

```
std::map < Int_t, pair <Double_t,Double_t> > new_map;
auto it = second_map.begin();
for( const auto &p : first_map )
    new_map.emplace( p.first, std::make_pair( p.second, (it++)->second ) );
```

or for C++98

```
std::map < Int_t, pair <Double_t,Double_t> > new_map;
second_map_type::const_iterator it2 = second_map.begin();
for( first_map_type::const_iterator it1 = first_map.begin(); it1 != first_map.end(); ++it1 )
    new_map.insert( std::make_pair( it1->first, std::make_pair( it1->second, (it2++)->second ) ) );
```

Comment: Assumes use of C++11, which wasn't stated in question.

Comment: @Steve that's standard for 6 years, I think we can assume it unless stated otherwise. Anyway it is pretty simple to rewrite it using C++98

Comment: then why is there a seperate tag for it on SO, if C++ is meant to imply C++11?

Comment: @Steve C++98 is also a separate tag, if C++ meant to imply C++98?

Comment: @Steve: C++ means _the current C++ Standard_. It doesn't mean C++11, it means C++14 and soon will mean C++17.

Comment: @MSalters I know, I just feel it's worth pointing it out - I've found it reduces problems when a (typically new to C++) OP tries the answer not realising the answer isn't supported on their environment. Not saying the answer was wrong, just pointing out a potential caveat.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant:

```
std::map < Int_t, pair <Double_t,Double_t> > new_map;
```

Iterate over the first map, and add the key and value to your new map using:

```
new_map [event_number].first = mass;
```

Then iterate over the second map, and add the key and value to the new map:

```
new_map [event_number].second = momentum;
```

I've assumed the 2 source maps contain the exact same list of event numbers, just with different data - if not, you'll get some entries in `new_map` that only contain one or other of the data

Comment: Thanks, yes the 2 source maps contain the exact same list of event numbers but with different data.

So I iterate over the first map in a for loop, do I then iterate over the second map in a second for loop within the first for loop or entirely separately?

Comment: @AmyTee `new_map[event_number] = { mass_map[event_num], momentum_map[event_num] }` should be enough. No need for multiple statements or temporary variables. Using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) could shorten it even more.

Comment: If you're already iterating through one of the maps to get the event_number, may  as well do `new_map[event_number] = { mass, momentum_map[event_number] }`, and save an extra lookup. Lambdas would require C++11, which wasn't mentioned in the original question.

Comment: This answer is slightly inefficient as you're doing two lookups of `new_map [event_number]`. The comments are better.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a similar algorithm to set_intersect while at the same time proving that the input data is correct for (almost) zero cost:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>

using mass_map = std::map<int, double>;
using moment_map = std::map<int, double>;

using mass_moment_map = std::map < int, std::pair <double,double> >;

bool merge_mass_and_moment(mass_map const& mass, 
                           moment_map const& moment,
                           mass_moment_map& target,
                           mass_moment_map& exceptions)
{
    target.clear();
    exceptions.clear();

    auto current_mass = mass.begin();
    auto current_moment = moment.begin();

    while (current_mass != mass.end() && current_moment != moment.end())
    {
        if (current_mass->first < current_moment->first)
        {
            exceptions.emplace(current_mass->first, 
                               std::make_pair(current_mass->second, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()));
            ++ current_mass;
        }
        else if (current_moment->first < current_mass->first)
        {
            exceptions.emplace(current_moment->first, 
                               std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), current_moment->second));
            ++ current_moment;
        }
        else
        {
            target.emplace(current_moment->first, 
                           std::make_pair(current_mass->second, current_moment->second));
            ++current_mass;
            ++current_moment;
        }
    }

    while (current_mass != mass.end())
    {
        exceptions.emplace(current_mass->first, 
                            std::make_pair(current_mass->second, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()));
        ++ current_mass;
    }

    while(current_moment != moment.end())
    {
        exceptions.emplace(current_moment->first, 
                            std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), current_moment->second));
        ++ current_moment;
    }

    return exceptions.empty();
}
```